# Как в ansible.cfg задать переменную при запуске ansible?

Tags: администрирование, ansible, devops

Я хочу подключить плагин `stdout_callback = myplag`, если добавить в конфигурационный файл все работает, но у меня нет доступа к этому файлу, возможно ли как то другим путем передать этот параметр при запуске playbook?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg#L4-L8 тут говорят, что конфиг может лежать в нескольких местах.

Comment: оказалось все проще, через переменную окружения передать в playbook и все, env ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook playbook1.yaml

Comment: Оформи как ответ со ссылкой где прочёл.